# jest unit test javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a unit test I am trying check the field but cannot find anything in the jest documentation to ignore the one value in this case, randomNumber.

```
const expected = [
  {
    model: 'string',
    type: 'string',
    randomNumber: 43,
    name: 'string',
  },
]
```

The random number changes every test so I can't hard code the test to check that number. I would like to test to make sure the expected array has all of the fields, but ignore the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
const requiredKeys = ["model", "type", "randomNumber", "name"];

const actual = [
    {
      model: 'string',
      type: 'string',
      randomNumber: 43,
      name: 'string',
    },
    {    
      type: 'string',
      randomNumber: 43,
      name: 'string',
  },
]

actual.forEach(x => {
  const keys = Object.keys(x);
  const hasAllKeys = requiredKeys.every(key => keys.includes(key));

  expect(hasAllkeys).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along the lines of this

```
const data =  {
    model: 'string',
    type: 'string',
    randomNumber: 43,
    name: 'string',
 }

const dataExpected = {
    model: 'string',
    type: 'string',
    name: 'string',
}

const {randomNumber, ...randomNumOmittedData} = data;

expect(randomNumOmittedData).toEqual(dataExpected);
```